# Why is nginx as apache front-end proxy not loading .html files?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, nginx, apache2

I was following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-for-apache to have a setup where nginx handles static stuff and all php files ares handled by apache on a fresh ubuntu box. 
Everything went smoothly and I installed a php script on the server.

However, it is not loading any .html files. All .php files are loading and working fine. Whenever browser requests a html file, the browser kind of redirects back to index.php (although the url ending with .html remains in the address bar)

I have double checked and I've done everything according to the tutorial.  What might prevent nginx from loading html files?

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    root /var/www/; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com; 

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

Below is the nginx error log:

http://d.pr/f/voxs

Comment: You should share your nginx config files.  You could have made more than one mistake in your configuration directives so any correct advice people give you would still seem to not work.

Comment: I've added my nginx config, Jonathan. Thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the interplay of `try_files` + your location block for php + your server/document root.

looking at the nginx docs ( http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files ) and the tutorial you referenced...

this setup is designed to failover to index.php if a real file is not found.  your root is `/var/www/` -- is there an index.html in there?  what do the nginx error logs say ?

Comment: @Jonathan Vanasco I think you're right. I do not have any index.html files there. I have html pages generated by the php script. Seems like nginx can't read the .html files and falling back to index.php. I've updated the question with nginx error logs.

Comment: 1. you're missing a trailing '}' in nginx ; you can run `nginx -t` to test nginx file for correct syntax.  if you try to reload nginx with a bad config, it doesn't refresh the config directives.  if you're been doing this for a while, you may have solved your issue and didn't know ( because nginx is still using the first config )

2. it sounds like you're explaining a slightly different problem - not that nginx isn't loading the .html files, but that it's not processing the .php failover correctly.  am i right ?

Comment: When I commented out  the try-files part, I got 404 on the html pages. But the .php pages are working fine as usual.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco The trailing } is there in the config. And nginx reloads are working fine. I just missed the ending } when pasting it here. And, seems like nginx is not loading the html files. And when It can't load them it falls back to index.php . So the .php failover is working fine.

Comment: the first line of your error log is `2013/02/19 14:49:08 [emerg] 5112#0: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:44`

nginx isn't going to reload on that error.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco Yes...but that error is a long time ago. I missed it when editing the nginx conf after installing. I've been trying to solve this for a long time now.